# Jackson deserializer - change null collection to empty one

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an entity that contains collection as attribute:

```
public class Entity {

    @JsonProperty(value="homes")
    @JsonDeserialize(as=HashSet.class, contentAs=HomeImpl.class)
    private Collection<Home> homes = new ArrayList<Home>();

}
```

If request contains null as request property:

```
{
  "homes": null
}
```

then homes is set to null. What I want to do is to set homes to empty list. Do I need to write special deserializer for this or is there one for collections? What I tried is this deserializer but it looks ugly (it's not generic and uses implementation instead of interface).

```
public class NotNullCollectionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Collection<HomeImpl>> {

  @Override
  public Collection<HomeImpl> deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return jsonParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Collection<HomeImpl>>(){});
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<HomeImpl> getNullValue() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

So few questions:

1. Is there some jackson property that changes null to empty collection during deserialization?
2. If no for the first point - do I need to write deserializer for this? If yes, can I write generic one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also couldn't find a Jackson property or annotation for this. So I'll have to answer no to the first question. But I would recommend a simple setter instead of the special deserializer :

```
public class Entity {

    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = HomeImpl.class)
    private Collection<Home> homes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setHomes(List<Home> homes) {
        if (homes != null)
            this.homes = homes;
    }
}
```

This is generic as it only uses the `Home` interface instead of `HomeImpl`. You don't need `@JsonProperty` as Jackson will associate `setHomes` and `homes`.

Comment: One thing that drove me crazy: You cannot combine `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSetter(nulls=Nulls.AS_EMPTY)`. You'll have to implement `JsonDeserializer#getNullValue()` and remove `@JsonSetter`

Answer (score 60):

As of Jackson 2.9, it looks like null-handling for specific properties can be configured with [`@JsonSetter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html), for example:

```
@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
}
```

Similar configuration can also be applied globally for collections:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapperBuilder()
    .changeDefaultNullHandling(n -> n.withContentNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY))
    .build();
```

Or by type:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapperBuilder()
    .withConfigOverride(List.class,
        o -> o.setNullHandling(JsonSetter.Value.forContentNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY)))
    .build();
```

I haven't been able to try the feature out, so this is based on the [feature discussion](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1402) and examination of [unit tests](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/filter/NullConversionsForContentTest.java). YMMV.

Comment: To be clear, there is not method `objectMapperBuilder()` in Jackson 2.9. There is `jsonMapperBuilder()` in 2.10, which is just helper method in Jackson tests and it just returns `JsonMapper.builder()`, where `JsonMapper` is a new helper class introduced in 2.10.

In 2.9 the defaults can be configured using `ObjectMapper`, like this `mapper.setDefaultSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forContentNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));` or for specific type: `mapper.configOverride(List.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forContentNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));`.

Comment: + @RuslanStelmachenko
`forContentNulls` is for null array elements,
the `forValueNulls` is needed for entire null array:
`mapper.configOverride(List.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));`

Comment: Note that per the Javadoc, this only works if the value is explicitly set to null, rather than omitted from the JSON.  `{"homes": null}` vs. `{}`.

Comment: @M.Justin You are right. So question is how to get empty collection after deserialization if the attribute is completely omitted in json (reqeust).

Comment: @sasynkamil initialize it with new keyword on field level, it won't be overridden by jackson

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was simply to remove the setter and make the attribute final. jackson 2 will then use the getter to modify the list.

```
public class Entity {

  @JsonProperty(value="homes")
  @JsonDeserialize(as=HashSet.class, contentAs=HomeImpl.class)
  private final Collection<Home> homes = new ArrayList<Home>();

  public List<Home> getHomes() {
     return homes;
  }
}
```

The responsible feature is USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS which is turned on by default: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution in my case which is working as expected (get empty list instead of null after deserialization) in both cases:

1. property is omitted in the json (request)
2. property is explicitly set to null in the json (request)

is:

```
@Valid // javax.validation
@Schema(required = false) // swagger.v3 
@JsonProperty(required = false, defaultValue = "") // jackson 2.13
private List<@NotEmpty @Size(max = 100) String> actions = new ArrayList<>();

public List<String> getActions() {
    return actions;
}

@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
public void setActions(List<String> actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
}
```

Notes:

- when property explicitly set to null: used default annotations
- when property omitted: added initialization `= new ArrayList<>();`
- when used e.g. java validation, then this solution is needed just for optional (`required = false`) lists

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.16, this can be set by using `configOverride`.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.Nulls;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableConfigOverride;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class Temp {
    static class Dto {
        public List<Object> list;
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MutableConfigOverride override = mapper.configOverride(List.class);
        override.setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));

        Dto temp = mapper.readValue("{\"list\":null}", Dto.class);
        System.out.println(temp.list.size()); // -> 0
    }
}
```