# Jackson global settings to deserialise array to custom list implementation

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml, jackson2

By default, Jackson is using `java.util.ArrayList` to deserialise a JSON array. Instead of this, I want to use a custom implementation. For example, Guava `ImmutableList` if value is present, or `Collection.emptyList()` if JSON array is empty or null.

I want to configure this globally for `ObjectMapper`. Is there an easy way to do this?

PS: My Jackson version is 2.9.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution is to use custom module. You can define classes you would like to use for collections. For Guava there is a Maven module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, you can register your new module:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// register module with object mapper
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

Now, you can define in your `POJO` you want to have immutable implementation of the list.

```
class Pojo {

    private ImmutableList<Integer> ints;

    public ImmutableList<Integer> getInts() {
        return ints;
    }

    public void setInts(ImmutableList<Integer> ints) {
        this.ints = ints;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo{" +
                "ints=" + ints + " " + ints.getClass() + '}';
    }
}
```

and below example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

String json = "{\"ints\":[1,2,3,4]}";

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Pojo.class));
```

prints:

```
Pojo{ints=[1, 2, 3, 4] class com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableList}
```

If you do not want to tie your `POJO` classes with `List` implementation you need to add some extra configuration using `SimpleModule` class. So, your `POJO` looks like below:

```
class Pojo {

    private List<Integer> ints;

    public List<Integer> getInts() {
        return ints;
    }

    public void setInts(List<Integer> ints) {
        this.ints = ints;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo{" +
                "ints=" + ints + " " + ints.getClass() + '}';
    }
}
```

and your example looks like this:

```
SimpleModule useImmutableList = new SimpleModule("UseImmutableList");
useImmutableList.addAbstractTypeMapping(List.class, ImmutableList.class);

GuavaModule module = new GuavaModule();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
mapper.registerModule(useImmutableList);

String json = "{\"ints\":[1,2,3,4]}";

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Pojo.class));
```

Above code prints:

```
Pojo{ints=[1, 2, 3, 4] class com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableList}
```

When you remove extra `SimpleModule` above code prints:

```
Pojo{ints=[1, 2, 3, 4] class java.util.ArrayList}
```

I do not see any point to use `Collections.emptyList()` in case it is empty. `Guava`'s module uses `RegularImmutableList` for not empty and empty arrays.

For converting `null -> empty` see this question:

1. [Jackson deserializer - change null collection to empty one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398885/jackson-deserializer-change-null-collection-to-empty-one)

but I recommend to set it to `empty` in `POJO` like below:

```
private List<Integer> ints = Collections.emptyList();
```

Comment: Thanks, Michał that what I was looking for +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that easy way exists, because `CollectionDeserializer` create instance of collection before parse. So, for this purposes you need to create your custom deserializer.

But I'm not sure=))