# Is it possible to use a custom serializer/deserializer for a type by default in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a type from a third party library (`JSONB` from [jooq](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSONB.html)) that I've written a custom serializer/deserializer for:

```
@JsonComponent
public class JSONBSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JSONB> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(JSONB jsonb, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(jsonb.toString());
    }
}
```

```
@JsonComponent
public class JSONBDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<JSONB> {
    @Override
    public JSONB deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return JSONB.valueOf(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to tell spring or jackson to use these by default without having to annotate every JSONB field in the project with `@JsonSerialize(using = JSONBSerializer.class)` and `@JsonDeserialize(using = JSONBDeserializer.class)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule` instance and register all custom serialisers and deserialisers. Next, you need to check out how to register new custom module in your version of `Spring Boot`.

```
@Bean
public SimpleModule jooqModule() {
    SimpleModule jooqModule = new SimpleModule();
    jooqModule.addSerializer(JSONB.class, new JSONBSerializer());
    jooqModule.addDeserializer(JSONB.class, new JSONBDeserializer());
}
```

Take a look at:

- [How can I register and use the jackson AfterburnerModule in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454849/how-can-i-register-and-use-the-jackson-afterburnermodule-in-spring-boot)
- [Jackson global settings to deserialise array to custom list implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255852/jackson-global-settings-to-deserialise-array-to-custom-list-implementation)
- [Jackson custom serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249054/jackson-custom-serialization-and-deserialization)
- [In Spring Boot, adding a custom converter by extending MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter seems to overwrite the existing converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761845/in-spring-boot-adding-a-custom-converter-by-extending-mappingjackson2httpmessag)
- [Customizing HttpMessageConverters with Spring Boot and Spring MVC](https://dzone.com/articles/customizing)