# Missing fields are getting deserializing as null instead of an empty object after upgrading Jackson-databind

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am facing one issue after upgrading Jackson library to 2x version, when fields are missing from input during deserialization, they are getting deserialised to null instead of empty.

Example -

POJO

```
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "ClassABuilder")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassA {
  private String value1;
  private Map<String, String> value2;

  private ClassA() {
    value1 = "someString";
    value2 = ImmutableList.of();
  }
}
```

Deserialization -

```
private final IonObjectMapper ionValueMapper;
ionValueMapper.readValue(value, ClassA.class);
```

ObjectMapper -

```
IonObjectMapper joiObjectMapper = (IonObjectMapper) new IonObjectMapper()
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS)
                .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
                .enable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY)
                .disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
                .enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```

Input -

```
{"value1" = "someString"}
```

Desired Output -

```
{"value1" = "someString", "value2" = {}}
```

Current Output -

```
{"value1" = "someString", "value2" = null}
```

Is there a way we can configure in the ObjectMapper that missing fields should not be converted to null but empty? I cannot change ClassA.

Jackson packages versions that I am using -

```
Jackson-core = 2.10.x;
Jackson-databind = 2.10.x;
Jackson-dataformat-xml = 2.10.x;
Jackson-module-jaxb-annotations = 2.10.x;
Jackson-dataformat-ion = 2.10.x;
Jackson-annotations = 2.10.x;
```

I tried the suggestion in this question but does not work for my case - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398885/jackson-deserializer-change-null-collection-to-empty-one/51442640#51442640)

Comment: What exactly have you tried from the given answer? Everything? Can you add such tries to the question? Can you also add your `pom.xml`? Thanks

Comment: I tried mapper.setDefaultSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forContentNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY)); and orValueNulls also instead of forContentNulls. Does not help with my case as you mentioned in your answer below. Updated the question with the jackson library version that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)` only works "when input contains explicit `null` value (...) is not usually used in case property value is missing" ([reference documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html)) which is not your case.

Your best option would be to modify the setter for that map attribute as follows:

```java
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "ClassABuilder")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassA {
    private String value1;
    private Map<String, String> value2;

    private ClassA() {
      value1 = "someString";
      value2 = ImmutableList.of();
    }

    public void setValue2(Map<String, String> value2) {
        if (value2 != null) {
            this.value2 = homes;
        } else {
            this.value2 = ImmutableList.of()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, modifying the getter/setter does work, I tried on a sample but as I was mentioning I do not have access to ClassA, so won't be able to modify it. Is there anything that can be done at the level of ObjectMapper so that it is globally applicable for all deserialization cases?

Comment: I think that there is something like `mapper.configOverride(String.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));` but this should be similar to `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)` so it wouldn't work in your case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As [João Dias already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69394908/10871073), the `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)` annotation is meant for explicit `null` values.

If you can't change `ClassA`, you could make a subclass with a default constructor that sets your `value2` to an empty map (assuming `ClassA` has a setter for value2).

```
class ClassAExtended extends ClassA {
    public ClassAExtended() {
        setValue2(new HashMap<>());     
    }
}
```

The variable you read to can still be of type `ClassA`:

```
private final IonObjectMapper ionValueMapper;
ClassA classA = ionValueMapper.readValue(value, ClassAExtended.class);
```